# Type 13 mismatch error in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

Dear friends I'm trying to display photos of the persons as per the name selected in a combo box.
I'm successful in doing that but my problem is that 
    while continuously choosing different names in combo box suddenly at times it displays          **  error 13, type mismatch** and my combo box too disappearing. But after that making the visibility of Mypics(Name defined to the table of person names and pictures) "TRUE" its appearing again after compiling 2 to 3 times.

here is my code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim Mypics As Picture

Me.Pictures.Visible = False

 With Range("B8")

   For Each Mypics In Me.Pictures

    If (Mypics.Name = .Text) Then

      Mypics.Visible = True
      Mypics.Top = .Top
      Mypics.Left = .Left

   Exit For
    End If
  Next Mypics
 End With  
End Sub
```

The cell "B8" is where the name of the picture appears according to the selected person name in combo box with reference to the Index number.

Comment: Check the format of the names, check for abnormal characters or spaces. I don't think there is a problem with your code it's rather the .Text or Mypics.Name. Do a `Debug.print mypics.Name, .Text` and you will be able to track the values in the immediate window when your code throws you an error. Also, consider stepping through the code each time you select new values.

Comment: which line raises the error? I don't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Often, cleaning up your code can produce wonders. I sincerely suggest avoiding using `With` if you're just aiming to use it once, as in your original code. How about trying the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim Mypics As Picture
    Dim TargetName As String
    TargetName = Range("B8").Text
    Me.Pictures.Visible = False
    For Each Mypics In Me.Pictures
        If Mypics.Name = TargetName Then
            With Mypics
                .Visible = True
                .Top = .Top
                .Left = .Left
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Mypics
End Sub
```

Let us know if this works. Also, try to `Dim` everything you can properly `Dim`. Often, a `type mismatch` error is thrown due to a variable being declared wrongly at the beginning of a code.